# Delete multiple postgreSQL records with python

Tags: python, postgresql, sql-update, sql-delete

My problem is that when I try to delete records from a table in postgreSQL with python I can't do it, the method I created deletes 1 by 1, but when I want to delete 2 or more at once I get an error, which is this,
TypeError: PersonaDAO.delete() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

The method I create to delete is this one, inside the PersonaDAO class.
In addition I have the classes of connection, that has the method to connect to the bd and of cursor.
Person class that has the initializer method with the attributes (id_person, name, last name, email).

```
conexion
from logger_base import log
import psycopg2 as bd
import sys

class Conexion:
    _DATABASE = 'test_db'
    _USERNAME = 'postgres'
    _DB_PORT = '5432'
    _HOST = '127.0.0.1'
    _conexion = None
    _cursor = None

    @classmethod
    def obtenerConexion(cls):
        if cls._conexion is None:
            try:
                cls._conexion = bd.connect(host=cls._HOST,
                                            user=cls._USERNAME,
                                            port=cls._DB_PORT,
                                            database=cls._DATABASE)
                log.debug(f'Conexión exitosa: {cls._conexion}')
                return cls._conexion
            except Exception as e:
                log.error(f'Ocurrió una excepción al obtener la conexión: {e}')
                sys.exit()
        else:
            return cls._conexion

    @classmethod
    def obtenerCursor(cls):
        if cls._cursor is None:
            try:
                cls._cursor = cls.obtenerConexion().cursor()
                log.debug(f'Se abrió correctamente el cursor: {cls._cursor}')
                return cls._cursor
            except Exception as e:
                log.error(f'Ocurrió una excepción al obtener el cursor: {e}')
                sys.exit()
        else:
            return cls._cursor

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Conexion.obtenerConexion()
    Conexion.obtenerCursor()


----------------
Persona and methods get and set
from logger_base import log

class Persona:
    def __init__(self, id_persona=None, nombre=None, apellido=None, email=None):
        self._id_persona = id_persona
        self._nombre = nombre
        self._apellido = apellido
        self._email = email

    def __str__(self):
        return f'''
            Id Persona: {self._id_persona}, Nombre: {self._nombre},
            Apellido: {self._apellido}, Email: {self._email}
        '''

--------------------
class PersonaDAO:
    '''
    DAO (Data Access Object)
    CRUD (Create-Read-Update-Delete)
    '''
    _SELECCIONAR = 'SELECT * FROM persona ORDER BY id_persona'
    _INSERTAR = 'INSERT INTO persona(nombre, apellido, email) VALUES(%s, %s, %s)'
    _ACTUALIZAR = 'UPDATE persona SET nombre=%s, apellido=%s, email=%s WHERE id_persona=%s'
    _ELIMINAR = 'DELETE FROM persona WHERE id_persona = %s'


 @classmethod
    def eliminar(cls, persona):
        with Conexion.obtenerConexion():
            with Conexion.obtenerCursor() as cursor:
                valores = (persona.id_persona,)
                cursor.execute(cls._ELIMINAR, valores)
                log.debug(f'Objeto eliminado: {persona}')
                return cursor.rowcount
```

with this method I can delete one at a time, but not multiple ids at once.
`

Comment: `PersonDAO.delete([person1, person2])` then  `def delete (cls, persons)` then in the method `for person in persons:   cursor.execute(cls._DELETE,  [person.id_person])`. **FYI**, if you use a single element tuple you need a comma after the element: `values = (person.id_person,)`. That is why I use a `list`, once less thing to remember.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know your framework, but i'd try this

the problem is in delete():

One way of doing it:

```py
@classmethod
def delete (cls, *people):
    with Conexion.getConexion():
        with Conexion.getCursor() as cursor:
            count = 0
            for person in people:
                values = (person.id_person)
                cursor.execute(cls._DELETE, values)
                log.debug(f'object deleted: {persona}')
                count += cursor.rowcount
            return count
```

Better way (but i don't know if your framework supports passing the list as a parameter):

```py
_DELETE = 'DELETE FROM person WHERE id_person=ANY(%s)'

@classmethod
def delete (cls, *people):
    with Conexion.getConexion():
        with Conexion.getCursor() as cursor:
            values = [person.id_person for person in people]
            cursor.execute(cls._DELETE, values)
            log.debug(f'object deleted: {persona}')
            return cursor.rowcount
```

Comment: I am only using python and postgreSQL, without any framework. Could you give me the example of how would be the command to delete there, if I want to delete the data with id= 13 and id=18 and what would be the error I would make above? thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: ```#Delete record
    person1 = Person(person_id = 18)
    deleted_persons = PersonDAO.delete(person1, person2)
    log.debug (f'Persons deleted: {persons_deleted}')´´´

Comment: @Tomm1s same as in your code. just pase my code instead of your delete method

Comment: i get this error:  values = (person.id_person)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'id_person'

Comment: this is strange. can u put the code to https://hastebin.com and share it here? @Tomm1s

Comment: the code is in spanish, https://hastebin.com/xaterehejo.py, thank you very much for your help

Comment: @Tomm1s it would be helpful if i could see the code of Conexion

Comment: Conexion: https://hastebin.com/xecazahaqo.py      ----    Persona: https://hastebin.com/yocudipefe.rb        -----      Log:   https://hastebin.com/damodihure.lua

Answer (score 0):

You did not say what Postgres Python driver you are using, but assuming `psycopg2` you can do the following.

Using a test example table.

```
select * from animals where pk_animals < 24;
 pk_animals | cond | animal |             ts             
------------+------+--------+----------------------------
         16 | fair | heron  | 
          2 | good | eagle  | 
          3 | good | mole   | 
         22 | poor | not    | 
         23 | good | not    | 2022-09-21 14:54:22.987311
          1 | good | crow   | 

import psycopg2

con = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test user=postgres host=localhost port=5432") 
cur = con.cursor()
values = [16, 23]
```

Using `psycopg2` execute functions:

```
for id_val in values:
    cur.execute("delete from animals where pk_animals = %s", [id_val])



# Doing basically same thing using executemany

values_many = [[16], [23]] 
cur.executemany("delete from animals where pk_animals = %s", values_many) 

# Using execute_batch which is more performant then executemany

from psycopg2.extras import execute_batch

execute_batch(cur, "delete from animals where pk_animals = %s", values_many) 

# All the above will result in:
cur.execute("select * from animals where pk_animals < 24")
cur.fetchall()

[(2, 'good', 'eagle', None),
 (3, 'good', 'mole', None),
 (22, 'poor', 'not', None),
 (1, 'good', 'crow', None)]
```

Using an array of ids:

```
cur.execute("delete from animals where pk_animals = ANY(%s)", [values])
cur.execute("select * from animals where pk_animals < 24")
cur.fetchall()
[(2, 'good', 'eagle', None),
 (3, 'good', 'mole', None),
 (22, 'poor', 'not', None),
 (1, 'good', 'crow', None)]
```

Comment: Hi, yes, I use psycopg2, when I try to iterate the ids, the first iteret is successfulI, in the second i got this error interface_error : cursor already closed, in the comments of the other answer I put some links with to the code

Comment: 1) Don't link to external sites, put the code into your question as an update. 2) The error explains the problem, you have closed the cursor at some point before the iteration completes.

Comment: I edited the original post and separated the files of the classes I use, I hope it is clear and you can help me, thanks for your answer. this is the original code, does not have the modifications you tried to make with an if